# Legal concerns in using/modifying/releasing codes

Tags: package-writing, copyright

In order to meet my needs, I copied 2+62 lines from a `.sty` file available from the Internet, and removed 10 lines, and added 12+18 lines of codes, resulting in a total of 84 lines in a new `.sty` file.

My question is:

What are the legal concerns in the following cases?

1. I only use these codes for my use. I use them to produce study notes and I plan make it free (freedom) so that everyone get the notes. No one will get those 84 lines.
2. I release those 84 lines in some way.

(According to the author of the original `.sty` file, I may use and modify the code, if I do not make a profit.)

I wrote another small file. It is completely written by me. If I want to release it somewhere in the Internet, how can I do it? I do not understand the meaning of licensing methods. I would be glad if anyone could provide me with some relevant information.

Comment: Well, if you don't make profit, there is no problem. If you distribute the code, you may want to cite the author. Or if you feel unsure, just contact him. IMO this does not belong to this side, as it is just about legal concerns and not TeX-related.

Comment: Well, most of us (except from the true gurus here ;-)) use some code seen in a style/class file. As long as you name the original author(s) and do not tend to make profit from selling your LaTeX code, there is no problem.

Comment: legal questions (as a matter of policy) are off topic but I'll note that if you are concerned about it it is highly unlikely that you need to alter the original file in any way. Almost any latex command can be redefined so your package can input the original and then change what needs changing. For releasing your own file, the simplest is to use the LPPL licence (as used by latex itself) and then [submit it to ctan](http://www.ctan.org/upload)

Comment: Since legal questions are off-topic, I voted to close (this is clearly a legal question). It's a pity really, because it's a good one!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Note that this question does not concern a file licensed under the LPPL which is the licence most of us are borrowing code under most of the time. I would be very reluctant to give advice on this even if I had read the licence which none of us have. [It cannot be LPPL precisely *because* of the no-profit clause.]